# Text Justified in IE8 gets cut off on the right edge

Tags: text, ie8-compatibility-mode, justify

Recently i noticed to this bug in IE8 (displays correctly in IE7), that the text gets cut off in IE8, just a bit and mainly all the "o":

The text is justified don't know if that plays an important role in this.

My questions would be, can this be fixed? is this a IE8 problem?

Thank you.

Comment: an example, or a URL showing the behaviour you describe, would help.

Comment: here are the screenshots: 
http://i50.photobucket.com/albums/f311/deadwinglullaby/web/text1.png
http://i50.photobucket.com/albums/f311/deadwinglullaby/web/text2.png

i am working on a localcopy at the moment, let me know if the screenshots let you see what i am talking about.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try padding-right: 1px;

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in IE8. I was having a similar problem: one of the last letters in a paragraph (l) was turning barely visible. When I selected the text, you could see it fine.

I was able to fix by turning on IE7 compatibility mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>
```

This was happening with

- IE8
- Justified text
- Zoom level increased by 1 (Ctrl +)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, and was able to reduce the cut-off in IE 8 by using the `-ms-text-justify` CSS property, like so :

```
text-justify: justify;
-ms-text-justify: newspaper;
```

This produced a noticeable improvement. However, some characters are still being cut off.

You can read more about `-ms-text-justify` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx